# Filter a given Column(count) based on timestamp Column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

1. I have a Pandas Dataframe which looks like below

[image]

- I want my Output or Visualization Plots which tell:
- During which Hour, how many Jobs have failed,completed (count)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only rows filled by `Failed` and then use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Status'].eq('Failed')]
out = pd.crosstab(df1['Hour'], df1['Job'])

out.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Pandas Version '0.25.3' : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'crosstab' i am checking what's the issue. does above version supports?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')

# status
status = set(df['Status'])
dfStatus = {s: df[df['Status'] == s] for s in status}

# hours
hours = set(df['Hour'])
dfStatusPerHour = {}

# calculate them explicitly
for s in status:
    dfStatusPerHour[s] = {h: dfStatus[s][dfStatus[s]['Hour'] == h].shape[0] for h in hours}

# show results
for s in status:
    print(f"{s} : {dfStatusPerHour[s]}")
```

Comment: {s}: is a string, would be more helpful if it's in a Pandas DataFrame so that I can drill down more data analysis on the output.

Comment: for s in status:
    output = pd.DataFrame()
    output = output.append(dfStatusPerHour[s], ignore_index=True)